# Having issue in my application form download

Tags: php

Having issue in my application form download.My issue is.once the form is submitted my java script code is not submitting the form to another page.page name is app_print.php.I have implemented js code in php.once every thing is correct.the app_print.php goes to download section.I have hosted in my webserver. Here is the link. http://lisieuxcbsekovai.com/application.php
Here is my code:
application.php

```
<form action="" method="post" name="application">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['application']))
            {
                unset($_POST['application']);
                if(isset($rep))
                {
                    if($rep=='sus')
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="sus cl"><img class="pa" src="controller/image/btn/tick_circle.png"/><?php echo $msg;?><a style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;" href="javascript:void(0);"><img id="close" src="controller/image/btn/cross_grey_small.png"/></a></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else if($rep=='fld')
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="error cl"><img class="pa" src="controller/image/btn/cross_circle.png"/><?php echo $msg;?><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img id="close" src="controller/image/btn/cross_grey_small.png"/></a></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else if($rep=='atn')
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="atn cl"><img class="pa" src="controller/image/btn/exclamation.png"/><?php echo $msg;?><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img id="close" src="controller/image/btn/cross_grey_small.png"/></a></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="lft_col" colspan="3" style="color:#DB0009">APPLICATION FORM</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">1.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Name of the child<span class="red">*</span><br/><span style="font-size:11px;">(In Block letter)</span></label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">2.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Sex</label><span class="red">*</span></th>
        <td>
            <select class="select_2" name="sex" required>
            <option value="">---Select---</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">3.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Name of Parents<span class="red">*</span></label></th>
        <td>
            <table  style="text-align:left;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="red">i.</td>
                    <th class="lft_col">Father Name</th>
                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="father" placeholder="Your Father/Guardian Name" required value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="red">ii.</td>
                    <th class="lft_col">Mother Name</th>
                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="mother" placeholder="Your Mother Name" required value=""/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">4.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Address for <br/>communication<span class="red">*</span><label></th>
        <td><textarea class="text" rows="10" placeholder="Your Communication Address." required name="address"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">5.</td>
        <th class="lft_col">Contact No<span class="red">*</span></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile:+91 999999999" required value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">6.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Occupation of <br/>Parents with details<span class="red">*</span></label></th>
        <td>
            <table  style="text-align:left;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="red">i.</td>
                    <th class="lft_col"><label>Father Occupation</label></th>
                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="father_occ" placeholder="Your Father/Guardian Occupation details" required value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="red">ii.</td>
                    <th class="lft_col"><label>Mother Occupation</label></th>
                    <td><input class="text" type="text" name="mother_occ" placeholder="Your Mother Occupation details" required value=""/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">7.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Date of Birth<span class="red">*</span><br/><span style="font-size:11px;">(as per Birth certificate)</span></label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Your Date of Birth" required value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">8.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>No of Year &amp; Months that will <br/>be Completed as on June 1st<span class="red">*</span></label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="age" placeholder="Your Age (YYYY/MM/DD)" required value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">9.</td>
        <th class="lft_col"><label>Religion &amp; Caste<span class="red">*</span><br/><span style="font-size:11px;">for Statistical purpose only</span></label></th>
        <td><input class="text" type="text" name="religion" placeholder="Your Religion &amp; Caste" required value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="lft_col">
        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="application" value="Submit"/>
        <input class="btn" onClick="javascript:window.location='application.php'" type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**application.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['application']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $sex=$_POST['sex'];
    $father=$_POST['father'];
    $mother=$_POST['mother'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $father_occ=$_POST['father_occ'];
    $mother_occ=$_POST['mother_occ'];
    $dob=$_POST['dob'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $religion=$_POST['religion'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $cur_date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    if($name!=''&&$sex!=''&&$father!=''&&$mother!=''&&$address!=''&&$mobile!=''&&$father_occ!=''&&$mother_occ!=''&&$dob!=''&&$age!=''&&$religion!='')
    {
        $con_qry=mysql_query("insert into application (name,sex,father,mother,address,mobile,father_occ,mother_occ,dob,age,religion,cur_date) values('".$name."','".$sex."','".$father."','".$mother."','".$address."','".$mobile."','".$father_occ."','".$mother_occ."','".$dob."','".$age."','".$religion."','".$cur_date."')");
        if($con_qry)
        {
            $rep="sus";
            $msg='Your application is downloaded, you can print the application from your download path.';
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var url='app_print.php?id=$cur_date&c_name=$name';window.open(url)</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $rep="fld";
            $msg='Registeration Faild.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**my app_print.php:**

```
if((isset($_GET['id']))&&(isset($_GET['c_name'])))
{
    $print=mysql_query("select * from application where name='".$_GET['c_name']."' and cur_date='".$_GET['id']."'");
    $p_r=mysql_num_rows($print);
    if($p_r>0)
    {
        $print_val=mysql_fetch_array($print);
        $aid=$print_val['aid'];
        $name=$print_val['name'];
        $sex=$print_val['sex'];
        $father=$print_val['father'];
        $mother=$print_val['mother'];
        $address=$print_val['address'];
        $mobile=$print_val['mobile'];
        $father_occ=$print_val['father_occ'];
        $mother_occ=$print_val['mother_occ'];
        $dob=$print_val['dob'];
        $age=$print_val['age'];
        $religion=$print_val['religion'];
        $cur_date =$print_val['cur_date'];
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Type: application/msword");
        header('content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name.' Application'.'.doc');
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>LISIEUX - APPLICATION FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" name="app_print">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><label><b style="font-size:29px;">Lisieux CMI Public School</b></label><br/><label>(CBSE Syllabus)</label><br/><label>Lisieux Road,Saravanampatti,Viswasapuram,Coimbatore - 641035.</label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="border-top:1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="border-top:1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="border-top:1px solid #000000;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">REGISTRATION FORM</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align:right;"><label>Reg.No.&nbsp;:&nbsp;<?php if(isset($aid)){echo $aid;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1.</td>
                <th><label>Name of the child<br/><span style="font-size:16px;">(In Block letter)</span></label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($name)){echo $name;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2.</td>
                <th><label>Sex</label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($sex)){echo $sex;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3.</td>
                <th><label>Name of Parents</label></th>
                <td>
                    <table  style="text-align:left;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td>i.</td>
                        <th><label>Father&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label></th>
                        <td><label><?php if(isset($father)){echo $father;}?></label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>ii.</td>
                        <th><label>Mother&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label></th>
                        <td><label><?php if(isset($mother)){echo $mother;}?></label></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>4.</td>
                <th><label>Address for <br/>communication</label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($address)){echo $address;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>5.</td>
                <th>Contact No</th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($mobile)){echo $mobile;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6.</td>
                <th><label>Occupation of <br/>Parents with details</label></th>
                <td>
                    <table  style="text-align:left;" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td>i.</td>
                        <th><label>Father&nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label></th>
                        <td><label><?php if(isset($father_occ)){echo $father_occ;}?></label></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>ii.</td>
                        <th><label>Mother&nbsp;:&nbsp;</label></th>
                        <td><label><?php if(isset($mother_occ)){echo $mother_occ;}?></label></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>7.</td>
                <th><label>Date of Birth<br/><span style="font-size:16px;">(as per Birth certificate)</span></label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($dob)){echo $dob;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8.</td>
                <th><label>No of Year &amp; Months that will be<br/>Completed as on June 1st</label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($age)){echo $age;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>9.</td>
                <th><label>Religion &amp; Caste<br/><span style="font-size:16px;">for Statistical purpose only</span></label></th>
                <td><label><?php if(isset($religion)){echo $religion;}?></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label>Date&nbsp;:&nbsp;<?php if(isset($cur_date)){echo $cur_date;}?></label></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">Signature of Parent/Guardian</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.open does (surprise) open a new browser window. Are you sure there is no pop-up blocker active in your browser? Otherwise you might miss the popup. You can debug Javascript with the F12 debugging tools in all major browsers. Set a breakpoint to the window.open line and see if the line is called. Some pop-up blockers also log to the console also available via F12

Comment: Yes now it is working properly.how to set the breakpoints to the window.open function.I am using JavaScript in php.is it correct? to retrieve the information  from filled form I have used the name and current date from db.because at  a time can any one fill the applicaton.so my application should work perfect.to ensure with you I have asked the question .check my app_print.php file and give response.

Comment: Did you get my question?

Comment: You're not "using" Javascript in PHP. You just defined it there (like any snippet of HTML). The javascript code is executed in the client browser. If your application works depends on what you want it to do. Please test it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` unfortunately has a way of getting 'blocked' by most browsers as an 'unwanted' pop-up if used during a page load - it is probably advisable to use a different way of calling the `window.open()` statement. An alternative way to accomplish what you are attempting (and side stepping popup blockers) is to consider changing your statement in app_print.php:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var url='app_print.php?id=$cur_date&c_name=$name';window.open(url)</script>";
```

to something like:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload=function () { window.location='/app_print.php?id=$cur_date&c_name=$name' }; </script>";
```

and thus not using `window.open()` at all.